# Using Python argparse, if the name of my output file is not specified, I would like the input file’s name to be used

Tags: python, argparse

All of the examples use `sys.stdout` as the default for an optional output file.  I would like the default to use the  name of my input but with the extension changed. For example, if my input file is `example.gif` then I would like the default output file to be named `example.png`.  I am trying to write a subclass of `argparse.FileType` to do this, but would appreciate it if someone has previously solved this problem.

Comment: What is the input filename? You haven't given us much to work with. I hope you don't mean sys.stdin

Comment: do you have to reuse it a lot? It seems to be easier just to add this specific check with the original parser

Comment: If you accept filenames as strings, rather than as `FileType`, you can easily test and substitute after parsing.  The default default is `None`, which is easy to test for.

Answer (score 0):

Please directly look at @alkasm comment. It's far better and shorter!!

I use something similar to name my default log files.
Could you try this?

```py
def change_file_ext(file_path, new_ext='.out'):
    from pathlib import Path
    in_file_path = Path(file_path)
    out_file_path = Path(Path(in_file_path.parent), Path(in_file_path.stem + new_ext))
    return out_file_path
```

Note that both `in_file_path, out_file_path` are instances of `pathlib.PosixPath`. That should be cross platform

For ex:

```py
print(change_file_ext('/some/dir/filename.in'))
print(change_file_ext('C:\\some\\dir\\filename.in', new_ext='.log'))
```

Will yeld:

```
/some/dir/filename.out
C:\some\dir\filename.log
```

Comment: Note that you can just use the method `with_suffix()` to replace the extension. E.g., `Path('somedir/somefile.txt').with_suffix('.md')`

Comment: Wow @alkasm ..I'm updating my log file pattern with your method!

Comment: Isn't `pathlib` great?!